# Java AWT/Swing: Get notified on change of position/size of my window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, listener

I've got a window and I would like to get notified when the position or the size has changed. Which type of listener is the best to take?

`WindowListener` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) which has the `componentResized` and `componentMoved` methods.

Comment: I'm curious as to why this is better than a ComponentAdapter. I tend to create a derivative and then override the ComponentMoved() and ComponentResized() methods.

Comment: The question was about which listener to use. People can choose to implement the interface or extend the adapter based on their requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try
the [HierarchyBoundsListene](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/HierarchyBoundsListener.html)r

```
        myJFrame.getContentPane().addHierarchyBoundsListener(new HierarchyBoundsListener(){

        public void ancestorMoved(HierarchyEvent e) {
            doSomething();          
        }

        public void ancestorResized(HierarchyEvent e) {
            doSomethingElse();
        }
```

see http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/eventsandcomponents.html for a full list of listeners that all swing components support.