# How do I listen for window size change event

Tags: java, swing, events, jframe, componentlistener

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java AWT/Swing: Get notified on change of position/size of my window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697966/java-awt-swing-get-notified-on-change-of-position-size-of-my-window)

Is there an event for JFrame size changing? I tried

```
addWindowStateListener(new java.awt.event.WindowStateListener() {
          public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
              System.out.println("Size Changed");
     }
   });
```

But it works only with `minimizing` and `maximizing`. I want to trigger even a small window (JFrame) size change done by dragging the edges. Thank you.

Comment: Please see [How to Write a Component Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697966/java-awt-swing-get-notified-on-change-of-position-size-of-my-window

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a `ComponentListener`:

```
myJFrame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Size Changed");
            }
        });
```